# Disable the error message (failed to execute script) obtained with pyinstaller

Tags: pyinstaller, execute

Hi how do I disable the error (failed to execute script) when i run a exe process created with pyintaller ? without fix the script , because the script works well

Answer (score 4):

"failed to execute script" says that your python program terminates with non-zero exit code by exception.
Try this:

```
import sys
def my_except_hook(exctype, value, traceback):
    sys.exit(0)
    return
sys.excepthook = my_except_hook
```